# How to push element in multiple dimension array at certain coordinate in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have an array like this:

```
    Animal[3][2][] animalArray.
```

After I have a new element like "dog", how to push it in the certain place at like

```
    Animal[2][1][]?
```

I tried

```
    animalArray[2][1].push(dog);
```

It always gives me the error.

Here below is the code with the problem:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Zootest {

struct Zoo {
    uint state;
    Animal[][2][3] animalarray;
    uint price;
}

 struct Animal {
    uint quantity;
    address Address;
}

mapping (uint => Zoo) zoo;

function openZoo (uint index) {
    Zoo memory newZoo = Zoo({
        state: 1,
        price: 0,
        animalarray: new Animal[][2][3](0)
    });
    zoo[index] = newZoo;
}

function enterZoo (uint index, uint x, uint y, uint quantity) public {
    Animal memory newAnimal = Animal({
        Address:msg.sender,
        quantity:quantity
    }); 
    zoo[index].price = zoo[index].price+msg.value;
    zoo[index].animalarray[x][y].push(newAnimal);
}
```

}

Comment: `animalArray` is a dynamic list of 2D arrays (of size 3x2), where each element in the array is of type `Animal`, is this really the structure you wanna go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to declare the array this way:

```
Animal[][2][3] animalArray;
```

From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#arrays (my emphasis):

> An array of fixed size `k` and element type `T` is written as `T[k]`, an array of dynamic size as `T[]`. **As an example, an array of 5 dynamic arrays of `uint` is `uint[][5]` (note that the notation is reversed when compared to some other languages).** To access the second uint in the third dynamic array, you use `x[2][1]` (indices are zero-based and access works in the opposite way of the declaration, i.e. `x[2]` shaves off one level in the type from the right).

Comment: Thanks so much!!! But if I put them in this order how should I initialize it? `new Animal[][2][3](0)` is not working anymore.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? With the declaration I gave, you should be able to just do `animalArray[2][1].push(dog)` as in your original question. There's no need for any sort of "initialization," unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Since this array is inside a class structure, so to my understanding, every time I new an instance I need to give some default value to every variable in the structure..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a class structure." Perhaps you could share your latest code and describe what issue you're running into if you just declare the variable as I suggested (and don't do any sort of "initialization").

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Its like this  `struct Zoo{Animal[][2][3] animalArray;}` so whenever I do this:  `Zoo memory newAnimal = Zoo({
 animalArray: new Animal[][2][3](0)
        });` I have to initialize everything, otherwise I get error message..

Comment: It would really help if you would tell us the actual error message you get instead of just saying "error message" or "the error."

Comment: That said, I'm not sure you can truly have this type of array in memory... memory-based arrays are not resizable, and this array doesn't seem useful without being resizable.

Comment: So again, you might have to share your _full_ code so we can see what you're trying to do and suggest alternatives.

Comment: Hi Smarx, I just attached my code above. Forgive me if my code has silly problems..I just start to play with sodality for a couple of days..Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just do `function openZoo(uint index) { zoo[index].state = 1; zoo[index].price = 0; }` instead. This avoids trying to create a `Zoo` in memory.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Just curious, if I wanna set a multiple dimensions array contents to 0, what is the decent way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can set individual elements to 0. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that should work. But I read there is a way to set on dimension array to 0 by using something like：'theArray = new address[](0);' Can it work with multiple dimensions array?

Comment: Yes. I think you could do something like `animalArray[2][1] = new Animal[](0);` but `animalArray[2][1].length = 0` seems easier.